# Steps to implement SAML 2.0 using C#

Tags: c#-4.0, saml-2.0

I am trying to implement SAML 2.0 in my project(c#). I researched and found the work flow. However I am a little confused with the steps from a coding perspective. Please help

Comment: Maybe you should do some tutorials and come back when you have a more specific question.

Answer (score 0):

SAML is not a simple protocol.

I suggest you use a SAML client side stack. There are some recommendations - refer [SAML : SAML connectivity / toolkit](https://nzpcmad.blogspot.co.nz/2013/06/saml-saml-connectivity-toolkit.html).